# Cannot use Duration.seconds method from kotlin.time

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to use the Duration class from kotlin.time package like this:
`Duration.seconds(5)`
But I see `Expression 'seconds' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found` in my intelliJ.

Not sure, how should I call this function then? Or is there something I'm missing?
For time being I have to use `5.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS)`

Snippet:

```
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime

@ExperimentalTime
class Temp {

    fun test() {
        println(Duration.seconds(5))
    }
}
```

I have kotlin ref in build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
}
```

Using it with kotest.
Here are my project dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:kotlin-extensions:4.3.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.+")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.12.+")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.+")
    implementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-allure:1.0.1")
}
```

[image: Gradle Dependencies]

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of your whole file including imports? It works fine for me: https://pl.kotl.in/0ZxjDCUOB

Comment: Update the snippet in question

Comment: Weird. You can try File -> Invalidate caches / restart.

Comment: can you check if there is any explicit dependency declared on kotlin standard library, ex `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:version`

Comment: no, I have again updated the question with the dependency subset snippet I'm using.

Comment: I have done `File -> Invalidate caches / restart` and removed gradle cache too. But still same problem

Comment: Why are you using @ExperimentalTime? It shouldn't be needed since 1.5.0.

Comment: Are you perhaps using an older version of IntelliJ IDEA with an older version of the bundled Kotlin plugin?

Comment: @k314159 are you sure? I see Duration class is tagged with @ ExperimentalTime. And If I remove it on my class, it throws error for the same

Comment: ```text
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)Build #IU-211.7442.40, built on June 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.57 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Non-Bundled Plugins: intellij.ktor (1.5.6), kotest-plugin-intellij (1.1.36-IC-2021.1)
Kotlin: 211-1.4.32-release-IJ7442.2
```

Comment: @k314159 I see `Kotlin: 211-1.4.32-release-IJ7442.2` in my IntelliJ info. Is that a problem? :thinking

Comment: Yes, that's Kotlin 1.4. Maybe try a Gradle build instead, which you know is using 1.5. Or upgrade IntelliJ IDEA and/or the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: @k314159: initially i upgraded plugin, but it didn't solve the problem. Then I did add kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21" in plugin section and restarted the intelliJ and now I no longer see the problem. I've reverted the plugin to use id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21" and it works. 

Side question, what to use?
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
vs
kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are importing the correct `Duration`

```
import kotlin.time.Duration
```

as there are other `Duration`s.

You can also use the extension function on `Int`,

```
import kotlin.time.toDuration

5.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: no, import is correct. But still I can't access any of those companion object functions.
As I said, I'm already using the extension variant. But I want to use this companion variant but somehow I can't. Trying to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```kotlin
    import kotlin.time.Duration
    import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes
    
    class Temp {
      fun test() {
        var d: Duration = 5.minutes
        println(d)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to use Java Duration, you can do this using @Francesc answer and the information in the link below is `(1.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS)).toJavaDuration()`
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/to-java-duration.html

Comment: Please provide a summary of what the benefit of the modification is and how it is achieved. Otherwise this (in my opinion basically acceptable answer which is based on an existing one) comes over as a code-only answer (because linked content is not considered part of an answer here). Which is still an answer, but probably one perceived as less helpful.